# Load json data to autocomplete jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use the jqueryui autocomplete to load services from mysql database on my form but nothing happens?? please help me or tell me where am wrong
my html

```
<input type="text" id="actual_service" />
```

my javascript script

```
$("#actual_service").autocomplete({
source: "http://dev_svr/medportal/search.php?callback=?",
dataType: "jsonp",
 minLength: 1
});
```

this is search.php

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'dev', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("medrep", $con);

$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

$qstring = "select  prod_id id,prod_name value FROM product where prod_type='SERVICE' and prod_name LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER BY prod_name;";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
        $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
        $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
        $row_set[] = $row;
}
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

when i load that page nothing happens on that inputbox when i type anything.

this is a sample output of http://dev_svr/medportal/search.php?term=ct when i limit the sql to 3 rows

```
[{"id":50,"value":"ABDOMEN SUPINE&amp;ERECT(2VIEWS)"},{"id":142,"value":"CT BRAIN"},{"id":115,"value":"CT CERVICAL SPINE"}]
```

Comment: can you see the post in the firebug?

Comment: i see no post on firebug

Comment: can you see any javascript error on page?

Comment: no i dont see any error on the page or on firebug

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Your jQuery code is not correct

You are not getting data from a remote domain, therefore you don't need a `JSONP` request.
It should be:

```
$("#actual_service").autocomplete({
    source: "http://dev_svr/medportal/search.php",
    minLength: 1
});
```

#### 2. Your JSON object is not correct.

Each json object for the autocomplete should have two values: `label` and `value` (no `ID`). If you want the product id to be the value of the selected item, and the product name to be the text that is shown to the user, then the json object should be like:

```
[{"value":50,"label":"ABDOMEN SUPINE&amp;ERECT(2VIEWS)"},{"value":142,"label":"CT BRAIN"},{"value":115,"label":"CT CERVICAL SPINE"}]
```

---

## Edit

From what you mentioned in the comments, try this jQuery code:

```
$('#actual_service').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://dev_svr/medportal/search.php',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

Comment: Thanks i have modified my code,i can now see the posts on firebug and even the response json is correct i have also done the changes on my php its now like this:
 `
$qstring = "select  prod_id value,prod_name label FROM product where prod_type='SERVICE' and prod_name LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER BY prod_name";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $row['label']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['label']));
  $row['value']=(int)$row['value'];
  $row_set[] = $row;
}`
but still nothing happens after i type anything on the input box

Comment: @indago [It's working fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/SdwaZ/). You need to type at least a letter in the input box, because of the `minLength:1`, for the suggestions to show up.

Comment: i dont know why its not working
but on the console i get the following error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/medportal/search.php?term=ct+a. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
jamuimaging2/medportal/search.php?term=ct+aFailed to load resource

Comment: @indago Oh, I see. Well, you need the cross-domain JSONP request then.

Comment: added the option `dataType: "jsonp",` but still nothing happens and nothing happens on firebug console either

Comment: @indago I edited my answer to add a jsonp jquery code sample.